# Why is my entity losing its id?

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jsf-2

I have a hibernate entity which is passed as parameter from a jsf view like this:

```
 private Block blockOrigin;
     public void methodCalledFromTheView(final Block block) {
          this.blockOrigin = block;
         //do some other suff
  }
```

But when I click the button again, calling the same method, passing a different block object, blockOrigin has a null id, but only the id is null the other fields are not.

My managed bean is ViewScoped and implements Serializable if that helps.

Edit: when I change to SessionScoped the id isn't set null anymore

Comment: Did not understand, "*but only the id is null the other methods are not*". Besides, you must have a correct import statement `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`, if the bean is managed by the container itself (CDI),  `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`, if the bean is managed by the JSF framework or otherwise if it is Spring, then that way.

Comment: This might happen if the `block` is actually a hibernate proxied object and you use direct field access for the id. If that is the case, try reading the id with a getter method instead.

Comment: @Tiny I meant the other attributes, not methods